# Why is my pixel manipulation script so damn slow?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I tried to create some blue waves, but the browser freeses if I run it. It works only, if I reduce the canvas's size to 80 & 60.

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

script:

```
var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas'), ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var imageData = ctx.createImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height);

for(var i=0; i<imageData.width; i++) {
    for(var j=0; j<imageData.height; j++) {
        imageData.data[((imageData.width * j) + i) * 4] = 0;
        imageData.data[((imageData.width * j) + i) * 4+1] = 0;
        imageData.data[((imageData.width * j) + i) * 4+2] = 127*Math.sin(i/100)+128;
        imageData.data[((imageData.width * j) + i) * 4+3] = 255;
        ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

What do I wrong? why is it so slow?

Comment: Well, that's a lot of pixels. 80 * 60 = 4800; 800 * 600 = 480,000

Comment: Even an animgif would be more feasible at these numbers...

Comment: Why di you perform the `putImageData` in the inner loop? Is it not sufficient to do this after all the data has been written?

Comment: try to put the inner loop invariant out of the loop: `Math.sin(i/100)+128`. No need to calculate it over and over in each *inner loop* iteration. So, instead of calculating it `imageData.width * imageData.height` times you'll be calculating it only `imageData.width` times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main slow down is because you are drawing the image at every iteration.

Move this line

```
ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

outside your loop.

Answer (score 2):

**Check out the crazy fast test**: http://jsfiddle.net/powtac/t8JA2/8/

```
    imageData.data[((imageData.width * j) + i) * 4] = 0;
    imageData.data[((imageData.width * j) + i) * 4+1] = 0;
    imageData.data[((imageData.width * j) + i) * 4+2] = 127*Math.sin(i/100)+128;
    imageData.data[((imageData.width * j) + i) * 4+3] = 255;
```

could be written as:

```
    tmp = ((imageData.width * j) + i) * 4;
    imageData.data[tmp] = 0;
    imageData.data[tmp + 1] = 0;
    imageData.data[tmp + 2] = 127*Math.sin(i/100)+128;
    imageData.data[tmp + 3] = 255;
```

I also included not_john's idea of moving the heavy assignment out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

One reason why it's slow is because you are executing certain calculations redundantly.

```
var value = (imageData.width * j) + i); // <--- cache this value
```

Save a property lookup

```
for(var j=0, k=imageData.height; j<k; j++) {
```